# Bad password when logging in via Remote Desktop

Tags: windows-server-2003, hyper-v, remote-desktop

I have just setup a windows 2003 server running in hyper-V.

When I log in via Hyper-V it works fine.

When I try to login via remote desktop I get a bad user name or password error.

I have:

- Disabled the firewall
- Enabled remote connections

Before I did the above I did not get to the login screen. I can ping the ip address of the image.

I am trying to login as Administrator.

Anyone have an idea about how to fix this?

**Edit**

I have now managed to fix this by changing the password to something without special characters. Strange thing is the I could not see any problems with the passord, had tried typing it into the user name field to check it.

Comment: Are you attempting to login as the administrator user or another user? If its another user did you grant them the necessary rights?

Comment: @ErnieTheGeek, thanks for the comment I have updated the question

Comment: What sort of special characters were you using? Interesting that it sounds like some chars are getting badly encoded through remote desktop. Sounds like a bug in RD? Or could it be a regional settings issue that the chars are encoded using the local computer system's settings rather than the remote computer's settings (would this even matter)?

Comment: @Chris J, it was //, when I type these into the username field they looked OK

Answer (score 0):

When logging into the Remote Desktop connection, please ensure the username field contains only the username (it may have the computername / domain pre-poppulated).
 Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the user you're logging in with is a member of the group "Remote Desktop Users"
Administrators should already belong to this group, but other users may not.